# Where are jQuery-UI scripts stored in MVC6 project?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm starting with MVC6 and I'm trying to use some jQuery-UI elements.

After installing the package, I cannot find the script files of jQuery-UI. While lot of tutorials on the internet tell that the files should be stored in Scripts folder (for example: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")"></script>`), it seems that it isn't the case with MVC6.

I saw this question ([How to get JQuery-UI to work with ASP.NET MVC6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943930/how-to-get-jquery-ui-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc6/33961189)) in which the file is retrieved from jQuery site : `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`.

Is there any way to have files stored on our server as before ? Where are these files stored in MVC6 project ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent a long time trying to figure this out when I first started using .NET 5 as well. Don't install client packages with NuGet in .NET 5. Use Bower.

To install it with Bower, expand the "Dependencies" item in your project in the solution explorer. You should see a "Bower" folder there. Right-click on it and select "Manage Bower Packages". At the top of the window that opens you can choose "Browse" and then search for "jquery-ui". It should show up in the list below and you can select it and click the install button.

Once it's installed, you can find it under wwwroot/lib/jquery-ui

Then, you can reference it like this `<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

--UPDATE--
I've been using NPM now for client packages, but the point still stands. Don't use NuGet for client packages.

Comment: For those also wondering, you will first need to install npm and bower before you can use bower in visual studio!

Comment: I think the answer to this question should also explain why we no longer use Nuget and need Bower or NPM now.