# Cannot add jquery using NuGet Package Manager in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I tried to add jquery to an asp.net core project using NuGet Package Manager of Visual Studio Community 2017 (version 15.5.2), but there is no jquery js files added to my project. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Tried with Bower Package Manager, then the files are downloaded to bower_components folder but not to wwwroot as many people said.

Same thing for jquery-ui, bootstrap, etc.

Anyone experienced the same problem. Is there any work-around?

BTW, this accepted solution doesn't work for me: [Where are jQuery-UI scripts stored in MVC6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554499/where-are-jquery-ui-scripts-stored-in-mvc6-project)

Comment: This seems to be Nuget's problem with .NET Core projects. We should use npm or Bower instead. More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485684/how-do-i-include-javascript-packages-i-install-from-nuget

Comment: npm is nice, if your project already uses Webpack. Otherwise, LibMan is easier, see the answer of psur

Answer (score 4):

For ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2017:

- **NuGet** shouldn't be used for client-side libraries.
- After that **Bower** was used for this purpose, but [now it is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower?view=aspnetcore-2.1).
- Currently the supported tool for managing client-side libraries is **LibMan**. [Here is very good explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1) how to use it in VS2017.